# More elegant way to do value comparison while preserving Nan in Pandas and Numpy Python

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I want `5 > np.nan` return `np.nan` or Nan instead of `FALSE`
In pandas series, here's the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[1,np.nan,5,1]})

a["x"]>a["y"]
```

will return :

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    True
dtype: bool
```

My current approach to preserve the Nan information is :

```
value_comparison = a["x"]>a["y"]
nan_comparison = a["x"].isna() | a["y"].isna()
value_comparison.where(~nan_comparison,np.nan)
```

where it returns

```
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

I took the similar approach for numpy comparison too

Even when the result is correct, I believe my solution is **not elegant**, is there any better(pandas and numpy) way to do this, which follows the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) ? (better readability, more straighforward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a bit improved/(changed) your solution:

```
value_comparison = (a["x"]>a["y"])
nan_comparison = a[["x", "y"]].notna().all(axis=1)
#alternative
#nan_comparison = a["x"].notna() & a["y"].notna()
m = value_comparison.where(nan_comparison)
print (m)
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Last is possible convert to [`nullable boolean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
m = value_comparison.where(nan_comparison).astype('boolean')
print (m)
0    False
1     <NA>
2    False
3     True
dtype: boolean
```